# Remove Specific Recycling Time For IIS With PowerShell

Tags: iis, powershell, remove

We need to keep an IIS application pool alive as long as possible for long processing.  The app pool in our std config has a 03:00AM restart in the array.  I need to remove this.  I can do it manually via the UI but it needs to be scripted.

I can see the the element with this code:

```
$pool = "IIS:\AppPools\my_app_pool"
Get-ItemProperty -Path $pool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection
```

That returns:

```
value          : 03:00:00
Attributes     : {value}
ChildElements  : {}
ElementTagName : add
Methods        : 
Schema         : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema
```

I can set the element (if I wanted to change it) with:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $pool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection -Value @{value = '06:00:00'}
```

But I want to delete it completely so there are no elements in the array.

I've tried:

```
$ArrList = @()

Set-ItemProperty -Path $pool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection -Value $ArrList
```

and variations of it, and NULL, but not able to kill the array or make it empty.

I am out of ideas for the moment.  Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't replicate your envrionment, but what about piping the Get-ItemProperty to `Get-Member` and see if there is a `.Delete()` method?

Answer (score 3):

This did it

```
remove-ItemProperty $pool -Name recycling.periodicrestart.schedule.collection
```